# Excel function as a string, called from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If i enter the following excel function in a cell and press enter, it works:

"=T_DisplayReport(A1)"

but if I write the following in VBA:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=T_LoadReport(""X"",""Y"",true)"
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Calculate

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=T_DisplayReport(A1)"
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Calculate
```

it doesnt work. How can I hardcode the cell A1 into the above VBA so that it is recognised and the function works?

EDIT: A1 contains another function which fetches data and saves it to the local cache. T_DisplayReport() grabs cell A1 to then display this data.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tested it and it works... Can you show us what the function does?

Comment: I cant really show, as its a custom addin function, but basically i have one function which goes and gets a load of data and puts it into the local cache. This second function then retrieves the data from the local cache and pastes it onto the sheet. I didnt write these so cant really offer code.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you test this for me... What does this give you? `MsgBox Application.Evaluate("=DisplayReport(A1)")`

Comment: I had to remove the MsgBox bit, but it still didnt evaluate cell A1

Comment: @Porcupine your code is putting the formula in A2, as you tell it too, so are you sure the input of A1 is providing what the function needs? what is the error, and where is the function defined?

Comment: i will show u what i have exactly in th original question...

Comment: No you are not supposed to remove the MsgBox. Create a new `Sub Sample` in the module and then paste the above code in that (with the msgbox) and now run it. What do you get?

Comment: MsgBox Application.Evaluate("=T_DisplayReport(A1)") gives me a type mismatch

Comment: I can definitely do simple stuff like "=D1 + D2" and this returns the correct sum, but this T_DisplayReport(A1) wont work

Comment: in you first example you have the formula as =DisplayReport(A1)  now it is =T_DisplayReport(A1)  which is correct? is this perhaps a typo?

Comment: @datatoo It was a mistake because I have to sanitise the code I put on SO because of privacy etc.

Comment: If `=T_DisplayReport(A1)` works in the Excel cell and `MsgBox Application.Evaluate("=T_DisplayReport(A1)")` doesn't then there is not much I can suggest without seeing the function...

Comment: @SiddharthRout If i clear the sheet of all formulae (so the only formulae is what you can see in my question) and then press my macro button, cell A1 says "retrieving data" and A2 says "waiting".... so A2 recognises that T_DisplayReport() is dependent on cell A1 completing its formula first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of Excel you are using, your Range.Calculate statements may not correctly handle asynchronous function dependencies. 
Try removing your first Range.Calculate and replace your last range.calculate with Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate or Application.Calculate